# Database not showing in SQL Server Explorer

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

I'm trying to use Entity Framework to `update-database`.

It's running fine with no errors. When I use `-Verbose` it's showing

```
Target database is: 'PokemonAppCore.PkmnContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention)
```

But in the `app.config` I've pointed it to a local db, like so. Nothing is showing up in SQL Server Explorer under LocalDb.

Why is it using `.\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `localdb` like it's specified in `app.config`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="PkmnConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=PkmnDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"  
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: do you pass PkmnConnectionString to DbContext Constructor

Comment: No, I thought I didn't have to because it reads from the app.config?

Comment: You must pass PkmnConnectionString to DbContext

Answer (score 1):

At first and as mentionned by Mohammad Akbari, it's important to pass your connectionstring name on DbContext constructor.

I'd like to add one more thing, the startup project (in VS solution) should be the one where EF is used, the update-database command is seeking for web.config (or app.config) of startup project.

Regards,